# gnutls-negotiate: GnuTLS error: #<process smtpmail<1>>, -15

Tags: email, smtpmail

Following [Sending Mail](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SendingMail)

> Since no credentials are given in this configuration, Emacs will look
>   them up in $(HOME)/.authinfo or $(HOME)/.authinfo.gpg (encrypted). The
>   content of this file should follow this scheme:
>
> ```
> machine example.org login [your login name] password [your password]
> ```

After finished the configuration and send mail

```
From: abst.proc.do@qq.com (abst.proc.do)
To: igabriel_job@163.com
Subject: Testing
Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2020 07:56:03 +0800
Message-ID: <874kwo2wks.fsf@foxmail.com>
--text follows this line--
Testing
```

but got the error:

```
 gnutls-negotiate: GnuTLS error: #<process smtpmail<1>>, -15
```

What's the problem?  I did not set gnus.

Ubuntu 19.10 emacs 26.3

Answer (score 1):

Change your port to use 465 instead of 587

```
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-starttls-credentials
      '(("smtp.gmail.com" 465 nil nil))
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 465
      smtpmail-debug-info t)
```